# The usage of “toodle pip”

Tags: word-usage, slang

According to the Urban Dictionary:

> *to toodle pip a dear friend* means *to say goodbye in a very friendly way.*

How common is this expression? Can  I use it without any fear to be misunderstood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression was common among upper-class English people around 100 years ago but is now very much obsolete. If you use it now you run a severe risk of not being understood or of being considered foolish. The Urban Dictionary is a VERY BAD source of information for English learners.

Comment: Are there any modern alternatives to it?

Comment: 'Toodle pip' was an old-fashioned slang expression for 'goodbye'. I've never heard it used as a verb _to toodle-pip someone_.

Comment: The etymology is fun.  Toodle from "toodle-oo" probalby from a "tout a l'heure" (see you soon, in French) and "pip" probably from the sound of a bicycle bell.  "Toodle pip" was always an exclaimation, not a verb.  Modern alternative: "See you later", which could be shortened to "see you"

Comment: Thank you both Kate Bunting and James K. That is very actually very interesting.